# Multiplying cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

How does one perform cycle multiplication? It seems that every textbook I read has a different notation for this and it's not clear at all. Suppose I have $(123)(134)$ now some book stated that the multiplication should go from right-to-left, but I couldn't find what to do with for example $4$ here since that doesn't map to anything? Doesn't that break the whole thing since it's not a bijection?

Comment: Not at all: $4$ maps to $1$, which maps to $2$. So, on the whole $4$ maps to $2$. In the end, we find $(123)(134)=(234)$.

Comment: Where is it coming from that $4$ maps to $1$?

Comment: The notation $(134)$ means, among other things, that  $4\mapsto 1$.

Comment: So I would get that $(1)(32)$, but the right side doesn't contain $2$ so what should I do here? If I would continue multiplying from the left here I would get that $(1)(324)$, which would be the same as $(234)$?

Comment: Not at all. Maybe you're missing that the product of cycles is just the *composition* of the corresponding maps (therefore starting from the right).

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56991/product-of-non-disjoint-cycles) answer your question?

Comment: Whether the multiplication is left-to-right or right-to-left is a matter of convention, and I’m afraid you are going to have to either check or deduce exactly how your source is doing it; there is no “right”(ahem) or “wrong” way to do it, just different ways of agreeing how to interpret it. But once you pick one way,, stick to it.

Comment: A number that does not appear in a cycle is mapped to itself by that cycle (so the cycle is still a function on the entire set of characters being permuted).  So in $(134)$, $2$ maps to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we multiply the two permutations $(123)$ and $(134)$ in that order, that (usually) means we first apply $(134)$, and then apply $(123)$ to the result:

- $1$ is first sent to $3$ by $(134)$. Then that $3$ is sent to $1$ by $(123)$
- $2$ is first sent to $2$ by $(134)$. Then that $2$ is sent to $3$ by $(123)$
- $3$ is first sent to $4$ by $(134)$. Then that $4$ is sent to $4$ by $(123)$
- $4$ is first sent to $1$ by $(134)$. Then that $1$ is sent to $2$ by $(123)$

Thus we see that the end result of applying this product is the same as for the permutation $(234)$. Therefore we have $(123)(134) = (234)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how is $2$ sent to $2$ by $(134)$? This is where I lose the track.

Comment: @Daniel What is there to say? The permutation $(134)$ doesn't move $2$ anywhere. So it stays at $2$. I said "is sent to" mostly to conform to the lines above and below. Also because one might think of permutations as functions, and in that case, we have something like $f(2) = 2$.