# How to decompose a permutation $fg$ into a product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

**Q:** Let $f$ and $g$ be permutations on the set $\{1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7\}$, defined as follows $$f=(436)(5124)$$ $$g=(2746135)$$

Write the permutation $fg$ as a product of disjoint cycles, separated by commas, (e.g., $(1,2),(3,4,5),\dots)$. Do not include 1-cycles in your answer.

---

My thoughts + working: First, I want to combine $f=(436)(5124)$ into a single cycle $(124365)$ (from multiplying left to right using $kp=k\cdot p=p\circ k$) because they are not disjoint because $4$ appears in both cycles.

Thus, $fg=(124365)(2746135)=(17453)(26)$.
Is my working correct, and could I have done anything better? (i.e. have I done any unnecessary steps?)

Comment: I explain how to do this (with composition right-to-left) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56991/742).

Comment: You seem to have miscopied your calculation of $f$ for the final computation, giving the discrepancy... With the correct expression, it seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to rewrite $f$ into a product of disjoint cycles first. Just do the calculation directly with all three cycles!

Looking at
$$(436)(5124)(2746135),$$
we have $1\mapsto1\mapsto2\mapsto 7$. So we start $(17\cdots$.

Then $7\mapsto7\mapsto7\mapsto4$, so we continue $(174\cdots$

Then $4\mapsto3\mapsto3\mapsto5$, so now we have $(1745\cdots$

Etc. Continuing this way, we end up with
$$(17453)(26)$$
in a single computation.

Comment: Thank you! I did think of doing this, but wasn't sure if it was an actual valid method.

Comment: @JasonXu Why wouldn't it? It's like calculating $hkg$ with $h=(436)$ and $k=(5124)$. You are just associating it as $(hk)g$ and then calling $hk=f$.